# VBA Code for Multiple Text Search in one Column from List

Tags: multiple-columns

Need to search multiple text in Description column from List column (which will be in different Sheet later) if Found the exact Item from List in Description column it will be return in Result column with comma after each item.

Please note that from this code there is a problem - see in Description column below picture, its mentioned "I am testing for SMDB" but in Result Column its showing DB MDB and SMDB. The Result should me SMDB only. Please advice

[image: Image for Ref]

```vba
Function aconcat(a As Variant, Optional sep As String = "") As String      
       Dim y As Variant
       If TypeOf a Is Range Then
       For Each y In a.Cells
       aconcat = aconcat & y.Value & sep
       Next y
       ElseIf IsArray(a) Then
       For Each y In a
       aconcat = aconcat & y & sep
       Next y
       Else aconcat = aconcat & a & sep
       End If
       aconcat = Left(aconcat, Len(aconcat) - Len(sep))
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not include the matching function code, this answer is a guess.

You have `DB`, `MDB`, `SMDB`, ... as searched values.
The text `I am testing for SMDB` contains the text `SMDB` but it also contains `MDB` (as S**MDB** contains the text MDB) and `DB` (as SM**DB** contains the text DB).
You could split your `Description` using different separators (whitespace, comma, semi-comma ...) to get an array of words and then try to match these words with your searched values.

Comment: Thanks you for your time, Actually the description will not change as the Item in descriptions will keep changing. I need them to search exactly which is there in List and matching with Description i.e. SMDB in Description will display as SMDB as one text in RESULT.

Comment: That's why in your search algorithm, you first have to identify the different words of the Description and then find the words that match exactly your searched values. Because I guess you currently only use the ```InStr``` function on the whole Description string, giving the wrong result

Comment: The search words will be in LIST. We have to find in Description and description will contain many words in it, we have to match exact word from list and if its there then put it in Result with comma aftr each word. Is there any other VBA code? Please let me know.

Comment: I have already totally understood what you need but, please, I don't want to type for you the algorithm that will parse a ```Description``` such as "I am testing for SMDB" into an array containing the values ["I", "am", "testing", "for", "SMDB"]. But once you have this array you can loop into it and check the strings/words that match exactly your ```List``` values. I don't know how to make my explainations more clear.

Comment: OK Sir, thanks for your time, but unfortunately I could ot write the VBA code, the above mentioned was provided to me by other person. Thank you Sir.

Comment: and he is not available hereafter